# JavaScript Optimization Script?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I seem to recall an online script that refactors JavaScript for the purpose of optimization (i.e, make it run faster).

I am *not* asking for a link nor information pertaining 'minifying' the code (and in broader terms, I am not talking about the load time for JavaScript). I am asking if there is a script that *optimizes* a JavaScript program.

I am under the impression that good C compilers optimize code, so it seems that some methodology would have came to be for optimizing JavaScript over the years. Is there such a service? And does such a service exist that is similar to 'minify' in the sense that it is an online service that you feed your JavaScript code in - and it spits out the optimized version?

Comment: As best I know, known safe and generic optimizations have been built into the latest versions of minifiers (like Google closure) or are being built into the latest versions of the JS engines themselves.  Since javascript is such a dynamic language, the kinds of things that can be done without knowing what the code actually needs to do is more constrained than it is in a compiled and statically typed language.

Comment: This is still a job a human must do.

Comment: Why do people keep posting answers as comments? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there are no javascript programs that optimize the code in sense of algorithmic optimize. Unlike compilers that do complex calculation base on information theory (they eliminates unnecessary loops, removes not used variables.....a lot of things) for optimizing the final machine code, Javascript is an interpreted(on the fly) language, and it's optimization is done by the javascript engine of the browser. Actually Google Chrome javascript engine seems to be the fast.